# How to Retrieve Form filled data in JBPM 6

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management

I am creating an application using Jbpm 6.4 . Every user task has a task form and I completed them through JBPM console . But I want to know how jbpm is storing this data  .Is there any way to retrieve these data's for future purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to retrieve the Task data since JBPM 6.4. In the previous versions, only Process Instance variables were persisted, but version 6.4 introduced the **Task variables auditing**. Task audit logs are stored in the **`TaskVariableImpl`** table.

Those variables are stored as simple Strings, like every other audit log in JBPM. Because of this, you have to implement custom `toString()` methods for your custom classes used as Task variables.

If you want to query for some of the fields of your complex classes, then you can implement your own `org.kie.internal.task.api.TaskVariableIndexer`. There is a great example at the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.4/userguide/ch08.html#d0e6057).

Although you can access Task variables in this general way, but for complex queries and high usage I would suggest to store the required fields in your own tables for better handling.